# How to properly specify defcustom default list of non-trivial data types?

Tags: customization, defcustom

How to properly write the default value for a non-trivial `defcustom` form in `standard` for something like I have below: a list of 3-element lists, with choices of the types?

The `defcustom` form is:  `defcustom option standard doc [keyword value]...`

The following `defcustom` works fine as long as it's default is nil.

As soon as I add a non-empty list of values in `standard` for the default value, Emacs `*Customize*` buffer UI fails (see below).

**#1: My defcustom form:** (with a `nil` value for the default, Emacs `*Customize*` buffer UI works fine):

```
(defcustom pel-key-chords nil
"..."
:group 'pel-pkg-for-key-chord
  :type '(repeat
          (choice
           (list
            :tag "expansion-keys"
            (symbol       :tag "mode           " :value global)
            (string       :tag "the 2 keys     ")
            (repeat
             (key-sequence :tag "key")))
           (list
            :tag "command"
            (symbol       :tag "mode           " :value global)
            (string       :tag "the 2 keys     ")
            (function     :tag "command        "))
           (list
            :tag "lambda"
            (symbol       :tag "mode           " :value global)
            (string       :tag "the 2 keys     ")
            (function     :tag "elisp code     "
                          :value (lambda () (interactive) <YOUR CODE HERE>))))))
```

The problem occurs when I specify a list of elements, or just one for default, as shown below:

**#2: My defcustom form:** (same code, but with an explicit default of one element):

```
(defcustom pel-key-chords
'((global   "<>"  "<>\C-b"))
"..."
...
```

With the default, Emacs `*Customize*` buffer UI fails: the `INS` and `DEL` buttons are not available and it is impossible to add or delete elements.

I read [Emacs Lisp Customization Settings section](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Customization.html#Customization) and some code like the [`dump-jump.el` code](https://github.com/jacktasia/dumb-jump/blob/master/dumb-jump.el) that defines some complex data with initialization. I assume I must identify some keywords in my declaration of the default, but for some reason I can't find the proper syntax for initializing the data I defined above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, murphy's law strikes again...

I just realized that the Customize buffer was showing **mismatch** beside the data structure...

The problem I had tied to the fact that the last element of my inner list is itself a list, and the default declaration identified just 1 string.

So instead of writing

```
(defcustom pel-key-chords 
'((global "<>" "<>\C-b"))
"..."
...
```

What I need to do is to write it like this:

```
(defcustom pel-key-chords 
'((global "<>" ("<>\C-b")))
"..."
...
```

and all goes well.

I wish checkdoc was able to catch these types of errors.

Comment: +1 for both the Q and the A. Consider filing an enhancement request to, for example, make the `mismatch` indication more visible, and perhaps let you click it to get some more detailed information about why the current value is a mismatch. Use `M-x report-emacs-bug` to file an enhancment request or a bug report.

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to figure out the first part, but then I stumble onto another issue: being able to declare a default using a list of different types. I edited my original question accordingly.   Overall I think the mismatch indication is visible enough, but  I would just like to see more examples in the manual.  As usual it's a matter of not knowing what you don't know....

Comment: You're right.  I'm doing that.

Comment: @Drew,  I restored the flavour of my original question and I created another question [How to properly specify defcustom default list of heterogeneous types?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/59057/how-to-properly-specify-defcustom-default-list-of-heterogeneous-types)